# How to enable non-minified compilation with the Ionic development server

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I am working on an Ionic 6 project, here is the `ionic info` output:

```
Ionic:

   Ionic CLI                     : 6.18.1 (/home/thomas/.nvm/versions/node/v14.15.1/lib/node_modules/@ionic/cli)
   Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 6.1.14
   @angular-devkit/build-angular : 14.0.6
   @angular-devkit/schematics    : 14.0.6
   @angular/cli                  : 14.0.6
   @ionic/angular-toolkit        : 3.1.1
```

When I run `$ ionic serve`, the development server compiles the browser assets into a couple of minified files:

```
[ng] - Generating browser application bundles (phase: setup)...
[ng] ✔ Browser application bundle generation complete.
[ng] Initial Chunk Files   | Names                                              |  Raw Size | Estimated Transfer Size
[ng] main.js               | main                                               |   6.36 MB |                 1.53 MB
[ng] polyfills.js          | polyfills                                          | 161.60 kB |                41.87 kB
[ng] styles.css, styles.js | styles                                             | 145.42 kB |                32.80 kB
[ng] runtime.js            | runtime                                            |   3.52 kB |                 1.64 kB
```

So when I am testing my application in the browser and, for instance, get an exception, the backtrace points to `main.js` and doesn't provide any useful information on where the problem really occurred. Back in Ionic 5, I would get a backtrace that would point at a specific place in my `.ts` files, which was much easier to debug.

Also the building time between each file update takes ages now (around 2 min)

```
[ng] Build at: 2022-07-29T08:04:04.378Z - Hash: fb8b64f788964cf9 - Time: 126572ms
```

How can I go back to a faster build time (in development using `ionic serve`) and, most importantly, how do I get more insightful backtraces?

I am guessing it has something to do with the compiler configuration in `angular.json` so I am attaching `app.architect.build` sub-tree below:

```js
"build": {
  "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
  "options": {
    "outputPath": "www",
    "index": "src/index.html",
    "main": "src/main.ts",
    "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
    "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
    "assets": [{
        "glob": "**/*",
        "input": "src/assets",
        "output": "assets"
      },
      {
        "glob": "**/*.svg",
        "input": "node_modules/ionicons/dist/ionicons/svg",
        "output": "./svg"
      }
    ],
    "styles": [{
        "input": "src/theme/variables.scss",
        "inject": true
      },
      {
        "input": "src/global.scss",
        "inject": true
      }
    ],
    "scripts": []
  },
  "configurations": {
    "production": {
      "fileReplacements": [{
        "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
        "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
      }],
      "optimization": true,
      "outputHashing": "all",
      "sourceMap": false,
      "namedChunks": false,
      "aot": true,
      "extractLicenses": true,
      "vendorChunk": false,
      "buildOptimizer": true,
      "budgets": [{
          "type": "initial",
          "maximumWarning": "2mb",
          "maximumError": "7mb"
        },
        {
          "type": "anyComponentStyle",
          "maximumWarning": "6kb"
        }
      ]
    },
    "ci": {
      "budgets": [{
        "type": "anyComponentStyle",
        "maximumWarning": "6kb"
      }],
      "progress": false
    }
  }
},
"serve": {
  "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
  "options": {
    "browserTarget": "app:build"
  },
  "configurations": {
    "production": {
      "browserTarget": "app:build:production"
    },
    "ci": {
      "progress": false
    }
  }
},
```

Comment: This won't be because Ionic 5 wasn't minified it will be because your sourcemaps aren't working for Ionic 6. You can try  ionic build --source-map to see if that generates them.

Answer (score 1):

I came across the same issue while updating old ionic projects.

As you guessed it, the magic happend inside angular.json (in app.architect.build). Inside the "options" attribute you need to add the following (right after the "scripts": []) :

```
        "aot": false,
        "vendorChunk": true,
        "extractLicenses": false,
        "buildOptimizer": false,
        "sourceMap": true,
        "optimization": false,
        "namedChunks": true
```

Those are the exact same arguments as you already have in "app.architect.build.configurations.production".
I guess only the "sourceMap" and "optimization" arguments are needed in your case, but newer projects import with the whole bunch, so I advice to do the same ;)

(didn't searched the meaning of each tho)